# reactjs web app QR code generation for mobile device image uploads

Tags: reactjs, mobile

I have a reactjs based web app, and i'm looking to create functionality where on the upload images section the user can either upload files from their desktop (this part already done) or scan a QR code with their phone to take and upload images from their mobile device.

Any recommendation of libraries.

I've seen this done on some finance applications in the process of getting documents to verify, etc.

I find it quite seamless from a UX perspective.

I've got the basic reactjs libaries working for uploading files, drag and drop, etc for desktop.

Want to make it seamless given the user will most likely need to take pictures of documents, but it's predominately a desktop application